# How to punctuate this sentence?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I was just wondering how to punctuate this sentence properly.

'They were, after all, merely extraneous extras - fighting a battle already lost.'

And if anyone has a better expression for 'fighting a battle already lost,' that would be extremely helpful too! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hate to be mean, but that really is an unnecessary tautology!

The expression is fine, although you might say [*lost cause*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lost-cause)¹.

---

¹ [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/)

Comment: How did you get a superscript?

Comment: AltGr + the number (works for 1, 2 and 3 here), 105-key "international" keyboard, GB layout. Linux / X.org / KDE 5, no idea whether you can do that on Windows. Also kind of cheating, those characters are a throwback to before HTML :o)

Comment: It looks as though you can do <sup>...</sup> in answers, though.

Comment: I haven't seen a list of html tags you can or can't use. I'm only on an iPad at the moment. Drive fried on the iMac.

Comment: It's cunningly concealed ... go to [/editing-help#html](/editing-help#html), there's a link from there to a list of what's supported.

Answer (score 0):

You've punctuated that properly enough that nothing needs to be changed, including the expression "fighting a battle already lost…"

That's a piece of poesy well-enough recognised to bring with it extra weight, but rare enough not to be clichéd.

That I don't follow what "extraneous extras" might have to do with fighting battles has no effect on the punctuation, which remains fine as it is.

(I hate to be mean, but I really don't see anything like tautology in there. Could Will explain?)

Comment: To me the "extra" in "extraneous" feels like it makes the "extra" in "extras" redundant, or vice versa. FWIW I did say the expression was "fine" (the punctuation is *perfect*, which is perhaps what I should have led with !).

Comment: @WillCrawford Yes, of course… but the tautology you complain of has nothing whatever to do with the punctuation Maddy Asked about.

I'd wholly support you in Asking a different Question, and d'you see how that would be a different Question?

Comment: I do see, yes. Sorry.